# Passing Variables By Reference using the ref keyword

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, ref

I try to pass a failedFlag by reference in PowerShell:

Function Call:

```
$failedFlag = $false

$message += createMSSQLBak -failedFlag ([ref]$failedFlag) -serverName "X\X" -backupDirectory "D:\ms-sql-backup\backup\X" -daysToStoreBackups 90
```

Function Prototype:

```
function createMSSQLBak ([ref]$failedFlag, $serverName, $backupDirectory, $daysToStoreBackups)
{
 [...]
 $failedFlag = $true
 [...]
}
```

$failedFlag is always false outside of my function.

Is there something wrong with the function prototype or call?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a `[Switch]` parameter, other than that you'd have to bind with a colon instead of a space between the parameter name and value when calling?

Comment: Could you explain more in detail?

Comment: Using e.g. `[ref][Switch]$FailedFlag`. But, on further reflection, there's no real reason to do so here, so just ignore that bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Get-Help about_Ref` has some useful code samples. They use **`.Value`** in passing without really mentioning it, but that's the key that you're missing here.

```
function createMSSQLBak ([ref]$failedFlag, $serverName, $backupDirectory, $daysToStoreBackups)
{
    [...]
    $failedFlag.Value = $true
    [...]
}
```

And that should do it. Turns out that `[ref]` actually makes it a variable of type `System.Management.Automation.PSReference`, which is a generic class with only the one property. It's not well documented in MSDN or even PowerShell internal help.